# Joining 3 tables Many to many relationship single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, many-to-many

How can I write one MYSQL query for the following

I have 3 tables

I know the logged in `user_id` is 25

`Users(id,first_name,last_name)`,

`userproduducts(user_id,product_id)`,

`Product(id,title,description,price)`

`userproducts` is a many to many resolved table

how can I write a query that will get me the `first_name`,`last_name` of the user with `id=25` and get everything in the product table of products where `user_id = 25` in userproducts table??

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple straightforward `JOIN` will give you what you want:

```
SELECT 
  u.first_name,
  u.last_name,
  p.*
FROM users              As u
INNER JOIN userproducts AS up ON up.user_id     = u.id
INNER JOIN product      AS  p ON up.product_id  = p.id
WHERE u.id = 25;
```

Comment: sorry Mahmoud it didnt work, note that it is the user_id which is 25

Comment: @user21 As thanks, please upvote my answer below, it was correct from the start. And put a @ before the names so they link to the user's profile.  Thanks

Comment: @PeterWooster - Sorry fixed now, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is done with two joins.  They should be LEFT JOINS if you want to get the users who do not have products.

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, p.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN userproducts up ON u.id = up.user_id
LEFT JOIN product on up.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 25
```

The product information will be null in the case where there are no products.  If you don't want the null products, use the INNER JOIN, also just written as JOIN that is found in the previous answers.

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, p.*
FROM users u
JOIN userproducts up ON u.id = up.user_id
JOIN product on up.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 25
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT 
 ut.first_name,
 ut.last_name,
 pt.*
FROM users              As ut
INNER JOIN userproducts AS upro ON upro.user_id     = ut.id
INNER JOIN product      AS  pt ON upro.product_id = pt.id
WHERE ut.id = 25;
```

Comment: Unknown column 'ut.user_id' in 'on clause' this is the error received

Comment: This is one problem with quick answers on this site, they take a few edits to get right.  This one finally looks correct.  the OP should look at later answers, they sometimes are written with more care than those racing to be first.